# jquery ui resiable- How to force to resize within the parent?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

There are three columns in a web page that are resizable. I need to

1. Force the columns width not to be more than the width of the parent
2. They all together must fill the width of the parent
3. Only the internal borders must be movable.

So if one column width is getting bigger, the other one must get smaller and vice versa.

To do so I need to I tried the `jquery ui resiable` and set the `containment: "parent"` but none of the 3 items are done. This is the code

```
    <style>
        .resizable {
            height: 300px;
            border: 1px solid red;
            float: left;
            min-width: 20%;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header text-right">{{ __('Messages') }}</div>
                    <div class="card-body ">
                        <div id="usersColumn" class="resizable">
                        </div>
                        <div id="messagesColumn" class="resizable"></div>
                        <div id="messageColumn" class="resizable"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $(".resizable").resizable({
                containment: "parent",
            });
        });
    </script>
```

What shall I do?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to:

> Use the containment option to specify a parent DOM element or a jQuery selector

[jquery UI - resizable](https://jqueryui.com/resizable/#constrain-area)

```js
$(function() {
  $(".resizable").resizable({
    containment: ".card-body"
  });
});
```

```css
.card-body {
  display: flex;
}

.resizable {
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header text-right">{{ __('Messages') }}</div>
        <div class="card-body ">
          <div id="usersColumn" class="resizable">
          </div>
          <div id="messagesColumn" class="resizable"></div>
          <div id="messageColumn" class="resizable"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is good, but here is problem, moving the right middle border causes movement of middle left border. It is not good at all. If I name the columns as `(1,2,3)`, moving `2` border to right must causes reducing `3` width and increasing `2` with. But it reduces `1` width as well.